# Statement with braces is not valid

Tags: java, syntax

Can someone tell me why this is valid in Java:

```
for (int i= 1; i<11; i++){
       Movie movie = randomMovie();
}
```

and this is not?

```
for (int i= 1; i<11; i++)
      Movie movie = randomMovie();
```

I do not get it because to me it seems to be the exact same thing, but when I put the curly braces, it suddenly turns correct.

[image]

Comment: It is all centering around the fact that the `movie` variable is local to that block.  In the second example where there is no brackets, no more code can be added to use `movie` hence it is invalid.  Even if you changed to `String x = new String ();` you would get the same error

Comment: It is because the types of statements that can be immediately controlled by a for-loop (or while-loop) do not include declaration-statements.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Java grammar forbids the latter.  The relevant grammar rules are:

```
BasicForStatement:
    for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement 

Statement:
    StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
    LabeledStatement
    IfThenStatement
    IfThenElseStatement
    WhileStatement
    ForStatement

StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement:
    Block
    EmptyStatement
    ExpressionStatement
    AssertStatement
    SwitchStatement
    DoStatement
    BreakStatement
    ContinueStatement
    ReturnStatement
    SynchronizedStatement
    ThrowStatement
    TryStatement
```

Note that the above do not include `LocalVariableDeclarationStatement`.

You can find the complete syntactic grammar for Java in [JLS Chapter 19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-19.html).

---

Hypothetical question for you.  Supposing that the following code is valid Java:

```
for (int i = 1; i < limit; i++)
     Movie movie = randomMovie();
System.out.println("The last movie is " + movie);
```

what is the scope of the `movie` variable?

The answer is that is must go out of scope immediately<sup>1</sup>.  Which makes it a *useless* declaration, and the usage in the `println` call is a compilation error.

I *believe* that this is the reason that they specified the Java syntax to disallow this.  The declaration is useless and most likely a mistake, and should be brought to the programmer's attention via a compilation error.

(By the same argument the declaration in

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++){
     Movie movie = randomMovie();
}
```

is also a mistake.  But doing something about this in the language grammar would be difficult.)

---

<sup>1 - The alternative is not tenable.  In a statically checked language like Java, you cannot have a situation where an in-scope variable only exists depending on an earlier execution path.  That would the value of `movie` be if `limit` was zero?</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works.

```
Movie movie = null;
for (int i= 1; i<11; i++)
      movie = randomMovie();
```